# Angular routerLink does not navigate to the page

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

So I try to navigate to other page, but nothing happening...
Can anybody help me, to solve my problem ? What do I do wrong ?

**My app.component.html** look like:

```
<a routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**My app-routing-module.ts**

```
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**My app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I expect it to navigate to the corresponding route when I click on it

Comment: Is the `AppRoutingModule` imported in the `AppModule`?

Answer (score 2):

try `[routerLink]="['/about']"`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: I can see that you have `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],` but you dont import no `Routes`, nor `RouterModule`

Comment: oh damn, my bad, forget to implement her :d